# Для чего выносят Service в отдельный процесс?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Можете объяснить, для чего `Service` выносят в отдельный процесс (при помощи добавления строки `android:process` в манифесте)?

---

Сначала я подумал, для того, чтобы, при убийстве приложения (смахиваем пальцем в диспетчере задач), он не умирал вместе с активностью. Как показала практика — он продолжает жить.
Потом я подумал, что это сделано для того, чтобы, когда сервис сам себя перезапускает, не открывалась активность — и тут снова не то! Активность при перезапуске не открывается.
Потом я подумал, что это сделано для того, чтобы не тормозила активность! Но тут на помощь приходит `IntentService`...

Так в чем же заключается смысл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IntentService` и `Service` различны и используются для разных задач.

По умолчанию `Service` действует в `UI` потоке, а `IntentService` - в отдельном. Т.е. при сильной нагрузке на обычный сервис будет "тормозить" активити.

Просто заменить на `IntentService` не всегда возможно и целесообразно, т.к. он используется для иных задач (единоразовое действие - сделал и помер) и, по умолчанию, не должен быть "долгоживущим", в отличие от `Service` (например плеер с управлением им из уведомления).

Таким образом `Service` выносят в отдельный поток когда он должен быть "долгоживущим" и, при этом, не должен "тормозить" активити.

Comment: Тем не менее, это не является ответом на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @metalurgus, я отвечал в меру своего разумения и с удовольствием бы почитал и иные ответы на сей вопрос.

Comment: Ваш ответ хороший, не спорю, но, к сожалению, отвечает совенршенно не на заданный вопрос. Так вот и мне бы хотелось прочитать обычным языком, зачем может появиться необходимость выносить сервис в отдельный **процесс**. Вы же объясняете по большом счету разницу между `Service` и `IntentService`, и рассуждаете на тему **потоков**